# How to render a theme if we passed via URL in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress site and I want to change every themes via query string URL.

So I have 5 different themes and want to switch over them via passing the name of theme in URL.

e.g.: I have themes named like (red,green,blue,etc).
and currently red theme is activated in wordpress admin and also I don't want to change theme from admin panel.

I just like to change theme via URL:

1. example.com?act_theme=red (Page should be display in blue theme)
2. example.com?act_theme=green (Page should be display in green theme)
3. example.com (Page should be display in red theme)

so here I am searching for is there any function or any plugin for it?

I googled this situation but doesn't get exact need.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the PHP [`GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) method in order to get the variable `act_theme" and set the stylesheet accordingly, so your function would look something like this:

```
<?php
    if(strcmp($_GET['act_theme'],'red') == 0) {
        echo <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="'.get_stylesheet_uri().'/red.css">
    }
    if(strcmp($_GET['act_theme'],'blue') == 0) {
        echo <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="'.get_stylesheet_uri().'/blue.css">
    }
    // etc... etc...
?>
```